# How does a vendor supplied C++ library support multiple compilers?

Tags: c++, linker

I make use of a vendor supplied library in a `C++ program`. All the vendor supplies is a `.lib, .dll and the header files.`

This library was first used in `MSVC++ 6` and now in `MSVC 2010.`

It appears they support mingw, qt, etc. I have had no problems with using it in either debug or release mode.

I have recently added another dependency to the project, `yaml-cpp`, an open-source project that provides no binaries. I am able to build yaml-cpp using cmake and MSVC 2010 as a static library and can link it to my project successfully.

In order to do this **I must link to the debug** and **release** versions of the `.lib` respectively as I have run in to weird Microsoft CRT/linker issues I am just learning about.

I am curious, **how does the vendor of my first library (libXl if you are curious)** provide a `.lib and .dll` that works on a range of compilers **without worrying about the CRT version**?

How do you write code that allows this or is it the linking process? `yaml-cpp` is a **cross platform library**, is it possible for me to compile it in a similar way that would allow me to use a single .lib within my project?

I am not sure what resources to look for to learn more about it. How do people learn about this kind of stuff? Thanks!

Comment: As far as i know creating a new lib project and all the settings should be ok. There are a couple of switches that can be changed like /MT but other than that it's all standard. If you use yaml with it's project provided by them then they might have some legacy compiler switches , you should try to make a new project for that lib.

Comment: If the library works with MSVC++ 6 amd MSVC 2010 then is most likely not a C++ library but rather a C library. The C++ runtime libraries are very specific to each MS version and can't be intermixed as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that a .lib and dll can work with a variety of compilers is down to ensuring that there are no compiler-specific dependencies in your code.  .lib and .dll are not recompiled so once they are made they should be stand-alone if so coded, and their functionality can be accessed from anywhere with the ability to use a .dll or a .lib.

There is some discussion on the pros and cons of dll and lib [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/95315/)  which you may find interesting.

Let me know if you need more info and I will do my best to oblige.